# Is there a best practice for sidebar width on mobile?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, mobile, best-practice, sidebar

What is the best practice when it comes to sidebars and user experience on mobile? Is it better to have one that is full-width or one that is 85% width with 15% backdrop? What are the benefits or downsides of either one?

Currently, I do it as in example 1 below with width of 85% and max-width of 360px (so it limits the width on bigger screens), but I was wondering whether I should change it to create a more app-like experience.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

one of the key-heuristics in usability is "orientation" - one must know where he's at, at any given point in time. 
hence, when using a 85-15 modal you help the user know where he is at and how he can "cancel" or 'return' to where he was a second ago.

note: this is theory. to say it was successfully tested - I DON'T KNOW. but it would be wonderful if you'll share an A/B Test (about this issue) results with us :)

good luck.